# How to decrypt a RS256 JWT using ColdFusion?

Tags: coldfusion, jwt

I am trying to decode a Auth0 returned JWT that has header information of:

```
{"alg":"RS256","typ":"JWT","kid":"thisisthekid"}
```

How do I decode the payload in ColdFusion? Is the kid the key to be used in the ColdFusion decrypt function? I tried using that with SHA-256 and I get an error that SHA-256 is not used by the sender.

Comment: There are various Java libraries that do this. There are a few CF wrappers of those libraries.

Comment: Ben Nadel has a JWT Token CFC that is pretty good.  https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2938-jsonwebtokens-cfc-a-small-coldfusion-module-for-json-web-tokens.htm.  It may be useful for this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `kid` stands for "JWK Key ID", it's a reference to an asymmetric RSA public key in JWK format. These public keys are available in the `/.well-known/jwks.json` route of your Auth0 tenant.

There are [various Java libraries](https://jwt.io/libraries?language=Java) capable of handling the token validation for you. The first one listed from Auth0 is probably your best bet.